# Problems with Logical operators. Confused mainly about && and ||

Tags: c++, logical-operators

I am fairly new to C++.

I realized by simply changing a logical operator, a part of my code becomes useless for the thing its made to do.

Can someone tell me why the following code wont help me in restricting an input of a number that's outside the range

Here's my code:

```
int main()
{
   int Xcoordinate;

    cin >> Xcoordinate;
        while (Xcoordinate<1 &&  Xcoordinate>10) //if i change the && into || it works like a charm
        {
            cout << "must be in 1-10 range sorry" << endl;
            cout << "Try again" << endl;
            cout << "X: ";
            cin >> Xcoordinate;
            if (Xcoordinate >= 1 || Xcoordinate <=10)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Can someone explain why it works if the `&&` is changed into an `||`??

Comment: && is logical "and" while || is logical "or". Do you understand the difference between them?

Comment: &&(AND) and ||(OR) are entirely different. In the case above, Xcoordinate<1 and Xcoordinate>10 will never occur and that is why your code doesn't work..

Answer (score 2):

You misused simple operators logic: `while (Xcoordinate<1 &&  Xcoordinate>10)` means that input should be *smaller than 1 **AND** bigger than 10* (the condition is equivalent to ***False***, since no number is that special).

However, `while (Xcoordinate<1 ||  Xcoordinate>10)` only asks for input to be *smaller than 1 **OR** bigger than 10* (which every number lower than 1 is, and also every number higher than 10 is).

Basically when using `condition_A && condition_B` you ask for both conditions to be true. When using `condition_A || condition_B` you ask for at least one of the conditions to be true.

Consider this instead:

```
int main()
{
   int Xcoordinate;

    cin >> Xcoordinate;
        // loops as long as Xcoordinate is not between 1 and 10 (inclusive)
        while (!(Xcoordinate>=1 &&  Xcoordinate<=10)) 
        {
            cout << "must be in 1-10 range sorry" << endl;
            cout << "Try again" << endl;
            cin >> Xcoordinate;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

&& this logical condition means both of the situations must be true.
|| this one means only one of them should be true and C programming language starts to read the code from right to left so if your Xcoordinate value is bigger than 10 then it doesn't look to other situation.

in your code your Xcoordinate value have to be bigger than 10 and lower than 1 there is no such a number. A number can't be lower than 1 and bigger than 10 at the same time. This is the logical mistake you have done. So it will never work if you use it like that.

```
 while (Xcoordinate<1 &&  Xcoordinate>10)
```

Comment: "...means only one of them should be true .." no, `A || B` is also true if both are true.

Comment: Yeah i mean for || one of them to be true is enough for the whole situation to be true.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the connectives.

Case one:

> If you have fewer than one banana *and* you have more than ten bananas

It's impossible to have both no bananas and more than ten at the same time, so...

Case two:

> If you have at least one banana *or* you have at most ten bananas

This is true regardless of how many bananas you have, so...

You want to switch them around:

> If you have fewer than one banana *or* you have more than ten bananas

```
Xcoordinate < 1 ||  Xcoordinate > 10
```

and

> If you have at least one banana *and* you have at most ten bananas

```
Xcoordinate >= 1 && Xcoordinate <= 10
```

As an added "bonus", the second condition is the negation of the first condition;

```
!(x < 1 || x > 10)
```

is equivalent to (check out "DeMorgan's laws")

```
!(x < 1) && !(x > 10)
```

which is equivalent to

```
x >= 1 && x <= 10
```

which means that the second test is unnecessary, since that's already the condition for terminating the loop.

```
int Xcoordinate = 0;
cin >> Xcoordinate;
while (Xcoordinate < 1 || Xcoordinate > 10)
{
    cout << "must be in 1-10 range sorry" << endl;
    cout << "Try again" << endl;
    cout << "X: ";
    cin >> Xcoordinate;
}
```